# Delphi XE2 Shared Respository

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

We have recently migrated from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE2. For both environments we use a "shared repository" on the network. This worked eloquently in Delphi 7 but we cannot seem to duplicate it in Delphi XE2. I have done so many searches on the internet and StackOverflow and StackExchange but cannot seem to find anything that resolves my problem.

Under Tools > Options > Environment Options I have a Shared repository specified (e.g. \DEVSERVER\ShareName\XE2ObjectRepository).

I am able to add my forms to the shared repository without any problems and they show up fine in File > New > Other under "Delphi Projects > MyStuff" (dummy category name for my example).

A repository schema file (RADStudioRepository.xml) gets created in the "shared repository" directory above as I would expect.

The problem comes into play when I try to inherit from one of those forms. I get the following error:

Unable to find both a form
(\DEVSERVER\EN\XE2ObjectRepository\UFrmLookup.dfm) and source file
(\DEVSERVER\EN\XE2ObjectRepository\UFrmLookup.pas).

As you will notice in the above error message there is a \EN\ added to the path name. I cannot for the life of me figure out where the heck that is coming from. I imagine if I could resolve that issue this would work just fine for me.

Can anyone help me resolve this? I have worked on this on and off for a couple of months but cannot figure it out. It's probably something obvious but I'm at a loss?????

Comment: You should be doing all this with your revision control system. That makes it easy. If you don't have revision control then you need to down tools and put that right immediately.

Comment: We were using VSS with Delphi 7 but recently converted to Subversion for revision control with Delphi XE2. I know we don't utilize revision control fully but it has never been a problem with the repository for inheriting new forms until we moved into XE2. I guess maybe I'm missing your point? We are learning with Subversion and it's quite a bit different than VSS but not sure where you're directing me. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: I mean that all project assets should be under revision control. And once you have them under revision control you don't need Delphi's repo. You pull the asset from your svn repo.

Comment: Ok I'll look into that method. We've just always used Delphi's repo. I guess it's just broke in XE2 since you have to use your revision control to do it (right wrong or other). Thank you for your response and clarification. Just seems like Delphi's repo should work.

Comment: I expect it does still work. I've never used it myself though. For the reasons above.

Comment: Thanks David for your help. We have successfully implemented this into SVN and it is working wonderfully. It took a while to get it all done but it's been in place now for a few months and couldn't ask for anything better. Much appreciated.